# where should I store my object in AWS Running Ec2 Instance With Application Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

if suppose we are hosting an application with application Load balancer and we have 2 ec2 instance. Both instance how can I keep sync .because if I will store the user data such as user image , document or other file inside the application folder .

if I store in one instance than load balancer will change the instance then user will not get the saved image or file because it will save in other instance ...

I thought About using S3 for storing user data but there will be much more charge because
there nay be thousands or more GET and PUT request will occur.
because when user will save or View Image in Site that will be count in Get Or Put Request

PLEASE HELP ME .. I dint know how to Solve this problem  with IN  COST OPTIMIZED WAY

I hope you are getting point . please give me solution or suggestion

Comment: Best practice is to store your data _outside of the Amazon EC2 instance_. This way, more instances can be added and unhealthy instances can be removed without losing data. Storing data in Amazon S3 will likely be a lower cost than storing it in Amazon EBS, plus there is no limit on the amount of data you can store. An alternative is to use Amazon EFS (Linux) or Amazon FSx for Windows to share a filesystem between the instances.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I am going to use EFS lets see how this will work...actually I am little bit confuse about using S3 because my will will have thousands of images so I have no idea how much request will be handling during user view or browse site there may be thousands of GET and PUT request by every single user. I exactly don't know  when will GET and PUT request Count

Comment: Retrieval costs for Amazon S3 are `$0.0004` per 1000 requests, plus Data Transfer. This means that 1 million requests would cost $4. The great thing about Amazon S3 is that you can generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that will serve the content to users without having to pass through your instances. This way, you can pay less for compute and let S3 handle all the load for serving files and images. That is likely to save you more money than S3 requests would cost.

Answer (score 1):

For keeping the state use something external, like you said.

You have a few options, like dynamo, RDS (Sql database) or S3. You are storing objects, so I would go for s3 bucket.

The cost is not so high. You can check them here:
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

You can archive not used files to glacier or even delete them after a period of no use.

Best Regards

Comment: Hello LEANDRO .. I have seen That https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/  but still i have not find any clarity about charges how will applicable for PUT,GET request suppose If we take an example of Ecommerce Site that has thousands or more products images then what will be charges of S3 for user browse the all products to find what he looking for and calculate that for thousands users simultaneously PLEASE CALLCULATE THE PRICING THAT

Comment: For storage $0.023 per GB in first 50TB, PUT, COPY, POST, LIST requests (per 1,000 requests) - $0.005, GET, SELECT, and all other requests (per 1,000 requests) - $0.0004. I was getting a look here and if you cloudfront this data transfer is free. A link of how to use s3 and cloudfront is here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/

Comment: You pay for all bandwidth into and out of Amazon S3, except for the following:
• Data transferred in from the internet.
• Data transferred out to an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance, when the instance is in the same AWS Region as the S3 bucket (including to a different account in the same AWS region).
• Data transferred out to Amazon CloudFront (CloudFront).

Comment: Thanks Leandro ..but I have found something called EFS  AWS EFS elastic file Storage it is network based shared storage Drive or Volume  which I mount in my both ec2 Instance and save my application data if I am not Wrong then

Comment: Looks like a good solution. I did not know this one. Looks like a S3, but easier to use. The advantage of cloud front is if you have users across the globe.